# How do you create a treemap in D3 with custome colors

Tags: colors, d3.js, treemaps

Does anyone know how to create custom colors on a d3 treemap without using color2 = d3.scale.category20c(); or d3.scale.category10c();?

Thanks so much if you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

category10() is just a special [ordinal scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#ordinal-scales). You can make another with your own colors:

```
color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd'])
```

Comment: Not sure about that, but i found a solution for myself, which i will share. I tried creating an assoc array of colors: var colorArr = new Array(); 
        colorArr["Agricultural Products"] = "#31a354"; 
        colorArr["Animal & Animal Products"] = "#9ecae1"; ...etc
 Then used a for loop to loop through the treemap nodes and assign colors to parent nodes. Hope that helps anyone else that may have suffered the same plight as i on this.